# Send Grid signup and Login Issue

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, nodemailer

tWhen I try to sign up for send Grid. They ask me some question that what is the nature of your bussiness
. I answer that a plate form of donation of bloods . They ask how you collect your recipient address provide link . I give him http://localhost:3000 link. Because I am using local host . Then move forward my signup process complete but still **when I try to login they still that you are not authorize to log in. So How I can signup and I can be easily login to *send grid*.**